# Displaying more than 1450 markers in Google Maps infowindows

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-markers, infowindow

I have already make some GIS web using googlemaps. but I have some trouble. I have to displayed about 1500 - 2500 marker and have infowindows onclick. 2 days before, everything fine, but when i add more and much detail in infowindows (before only have 4 detail info like name, address, etc and now there is 9 detail info), the marker did not appear. I am using Json message function to get value from database and displayed in infowindows. if it's 1450 markers, it's work fine, but when markers more than that, the markers did not displayed on map. does it memory cache or cookies problem ?? Please help. Thanks.  I am using googlechrome, Postgre database, PHP and googlemaps api v3.

```
<?php  
require ('config.php');
$rayon = $_POST['rayon'];
$cabang = $_POST['org_id'];
//echo "$rayon, $cabang, $rayonhasil";
$sql = "SELECT distinct org_id, cp_customer_site_use_id, customer_name, address, postal_code, city, cp_rayon_name, icon_rayon, attribute16, attribute17 FROM hasilgis";
$data = pg_query($sql);
$json = '{"enseval": {';
$json .= '"customer":[ ';
while($x = pg_fetch_array($data)){
    $json .= '{';
    $json .= '"id_customer":"'.$x['org_id'].'",
        "id_photo":"'.$x['cp_customer_site_use_id'].'",
        "postal_code":"'.$x['postal_code'].'",
        "nama_customer":"'.htmlspecialchars($x['customer_name']).'",
        "city":"'.htmlspecialchars($x['city']).'",
        "address":"'.htmlspecialchars($x['address']).'",
        "nama_rayon":"'.htmlspecialchars($x['cp_rayon_name']).'",
        "icon":"'.$x['icon_rayon'].'",
        "x":"'.$x['attribute16'].'",
        "y":"'.$x['attribute17'].'"
    },';
}
$json = substr($json,0,strlen($json)-1);
$json .= ']';
$json .= '}}';

echo $json;
?>
```

---

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function initialize(){
    var peta;
    var x = new Array();
    var y = new Array();
    var customer_name = new Array();
    var cp_rayon_name = new Array();
    var icon = new Array();
    var photo = new Array();
    var city = new Array();
    var address = new Array();
    var postal_code = new Array();
    // posisi default peta saat diload
    var lokasibaru = new google.maps.LatLng( -1.2653859,116.83119999999997);
    var petaoption = {
        zoom: 5,
        center: lokasibaru,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        peta = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),petaoption);
        var infowindow =  new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                      content: ''
        });
    // memanggil function untuk menampilkan koordinat
        url = "json.php";
        $.ajax({
        url: url,
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        success: function(msg){
            for(i=0;i<msg.enseval.customer.length;i++){
                x[i] = msg.enseval.customer[i].x;
                y[i] = msg.enseval.customer[i].y;
                customer_name[i] = msg.enseval.customer[i].nama_customer;
                cp_rayon_name[i] = msg.enseval.customer[i].nama_rayon;
                icon[i] = msg.enseval.customer[i].icon;
                photo[i] = msg.enseval.customer[i].id_photo;
                city[i] = msg.enseval.customer[i].city;
                address[i] = msg.enseval.customer[i].address;
                postal_code[i] = msg.enseval.customer[i].postal_code;
                var point = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(msg.enseval.customer[i].x),parseFloat(msg.enseval.customer[i].y));
                var gambar_tanda = 'assets/images/'+msg.enseval.customer[i].icon+'.png';
                var photo_cust = '<img src="assets/images/foto_cust/'+msg.enseval.customer[i].id_photo+'_1.jpg" style="width:200px;height:120px;"/>';
                //var nm_cust = msg.enseval.customer[i].nama_customer;
                //var nm_rayon = , msg.enseval.customer[i].nama_rayon;
                var html = '<b>' + customer_name[i] + '</b><br/>'+city[i]+ ', '+address[i]+', '+postal_code[i]+'<br/>' + cp_rayon_name[i] + '<br/>' + photo_cust;
                tanda = new google.maps.Marker({
                            position: point,
                            map: peta,
                            icon: gambar_tanda,
                            clickable: true
                });
            bindInfoWindow(tanda, peta, infowindow, html  );
            }
        }
        });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
function bindInfoWindow(tanda, peta, infowindow, data) {
    google.maps.event.addListener(tanda, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.setContent(data);
    infowindow.open(peta, tanda);
    });
}
function reload(form){
    var val=form.org_id.options[form.org_id.options.selectedIndex].value;
    self.location='main_page.php?cabang=' + val ;
}
</script>
    <!--[if IE]><script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script><![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper"><!-- #wrapper -->
    <header><!-- header -->
        <br><br><br>
        <h1></h1>
    </header><!-- end of header -->

    <section id="main"><!-- #main content area -->
<div id="map_canvas" style=" align: left; width:1000px; height:500px"></div><br>
<?php require ('config.php'); 
    @$cabang=$_GET['cabang'];
    /*if(strlen($cabang) > 0 and !is_numeric($cabang)){ 
    echo "Data Error";
    exit;
    }*/
    $quer2=pg_query("SELECT DISTINCT orgid FROM epmgis order by orgid");
    if(isset($cabang) and strlen($cabang)){
        $quer=pg_query("SELECT DISTINCT nm_rayon FROM epmgis where orgid=$cabang order by nm_rayon"); 
    }
    else{$quer=pg_query("SELECT DISTINCT nm_rayon FROM epmgis order by nm_rayon"); }
        echo"<table>";
            echo"<tr>";
        echo "<form method=post name=f1 action='proses_map.php'>";
        echo " <td>Silahkan Pilih Kode Cabang </td><td>:</td><td><select name='org_id' onchange=\"reload(this.form)\"><option value=''></option>";
            while($noticia2 = pg_fetch_array($quer2)) { 
                if($noticia2['orgid']==@$cabang){echo "<option selected value='$noticia2[orgid]'>$noticia2[orgid]</option>"."<BR>";}
                    else{echo  "<option value='$noticia2[orgid]'>$noticia2[orgid]</option>";}
                }
                    echo "</select></td></tr>";
                    echo"<br>";
                    echo "<tr><td>Silahkan Pilih Rayon</td><td>:</td><td><select name='rayon'><option value=''></option>";
            while($noticia = pg_fetch_array($quer)) { 
                    echo  "<option value='$noticia[nm_rayon]'>$noticia[nm_rayon]</option>";
            }
                    echo "</select></td></tr>";
                    echo "<tr><td><input type=submit value=Submit>";
                    echo "</form>";
        echo"</td></tr>";
        echo"</table>";
?>
```

Comment: I'm not sure how you expect us to help.  What javascript errors do you get when it doesn't work? What does your code look like?  Can you provide a link to a map that exhibits the problem?  Or a jsfiddle?

Comment: the error just the markers did not show in map when it's about 1600 markers and more. i will give you the code. i expect that may be you have already experienced problem like me and know how to solve it .

Comment: What browser are you using?  Did you check the javascript console for errors?  Can you provide an example that exhibits the problem (2nd request for a link or a jsfiddle)?  Without your data, and/or your database, your PHP is useless (at least to me).  Usually when adding data causes a problem, it is a problem in the data, not the code...

Comment: You better use json_encode instead of "manuallly" creating the JSON to avoid invalid characters inside the JSON

Comment: @dr.molle thanks, i will try this out, may be this is the solution but i never using the json_encode, but great thanks for the information.